# Browser wants to download Json as a file when returning Json from the controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

```
  $("#frmCompose").submit(function () {

            $(this).ajaxSubmit({

                success: function (response) {
                    alert('success');
                }
            });

        });
```

Controller code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendEmail(EmailMessageModel emailMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                // do something with the data
                return Json(new StatusModel { error = false });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(new StatusModel { error = true, message = "Could not send email" });
            }
        }
```

View Code:

```
<form id="frmCompose" method="post" action="SendEmail">
    <button id="compose" class="btn-pencil">
        Send</button>
    <div class="fields-inline">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("To:")
        </div>
        @Html.TextBox("txtTo")
    </div>
    <div class="fields-inline">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Subject:")
        </div>
        @Html.TextBox("txtSubject")
    </div>
    <div class="fields-inline">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Body:")
        </div>
        @Html.TextArea("txtBody")
    </div>
</form>
```

In my controller I return a JSon result with a text message.
Why does the view in FireFox want to download the json as a file download?

All I want to do is ensure I get a response within the success callback

Comment: Are you seeing this when you make the AJAX call, or when you go to the address in the browser address bar?

Comment: can you post your controller code? Alternativly specify `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax request.

Comment: @DanielB - I've added an edit to original post.

Comment: @dlev - it happens in the ajax call not on browser address bar

Comment: I worked it out, I need to return false inside the .submit() function and it seems ok!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to return false within the submit() call function for the form.

That way, the json result is consumed within the submit function and not passed to the browser for handling.

```
$("#frmCompose").submit(function () {

            // submit data to server here....


            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload):

> Since it is not possible to upload
>   files using the browser's
>   XMLHttpRequest object, the Form Plugin
>   uses a hidden iframe element to help
>   with the task. This is a common
>   technique, but it has inherent
>   limitations. The iframe element is
>   used as the target of the form's
>   submit operation which means that the
>   server response is written to the
>   iframe. This is fine if the response
>   type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work
>   as well if the response type is script
>   or JSON, both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented
>   using entity references when found in
>   HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of
>   script and JSON responses, the Form
>   Plugin allows these responses to be
>   embedded in a textarea element and it
>   is recommended that you do so for
>   these response types when used in
>   conjuction with file uploads.

This basically means that if you want to upload files using the jquery form plugin and your form contains file input fields the server needs to wrap the returned JSON into `<textarea>` tags.